# Cant share links to facebook from my site.No link and no thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

Hi guys im new to wordpress even i have website for 2 years i never had any problem like today. I cant share any links to facebook from my website. I mean i can share but there is no link or thumbnail image just my website name on blank white square.  Every friend i asked to try to share from my site said some links work and some dont, most dont. When i go to facebook debuger i get this

[image: Facebook Debuger]

Like i said i have no idea what is going on here. Any help please im desperate !!! My website is receptizasve.com

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying to use. this is the only way how you can get help. Take a look of the help section to see hot to ask on Stackoverflow

Comment: Provide some more information including the code, a specific URL and steps to recreate. It sounds like an issue with your SEO optimisation, potentially not a code problem - take a look at [Yoast SEO](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj3ncfCz6XXAhXCtBoKHd9rBHEQFggwMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen-gb.wordpress.org%2Fplugins%2Fwordpress-seo%2F&usg=AOvVaw1rZbzqet-J5mmAMzmlVXhd)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing the Yoast SEO. From there in the social media window I was able to edit the appearance of any link posts. I changed the thumbnail image to be my site's logo. I think that is your best bet.

Comment: I already tryed that man, even when i add picture to yoas SEO when i share link from my website there is still no image or link :(

Comment: Other then that and the Facebook Debugger what other methods/links have you looked into?

Comment: I tryed litteraly every solution i find online. I even reinstal my windows 10 today. Didnt work. I tryed deleting all plugins from my wordpress instalation , didnt help. Reinstalled SEO ans tryed again. Nothing. Im not werry techy guy in wordpress. Im still trying to contact Godaddy chat support to check with them if its maybe domain problem but there is nobody online :( Duuno what to do any more man :(

Comment: So I tried sharing your link. It does work when you include "www."